# Animate a transformed (rotated) SVG group with animate tag

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, svg, fabricjs

I'm wanting to animate an SVG group that has been transformed (rotated). To do this, I am inserting animate tags. In my example, I am animating a vertical line element, so the animate tags are inserted before the closing line tag. This works amazingly well if the line has not been rotated. However, after rotating the line, the entire context is rotated, and my animation instructions are rotated as well. I'm wanting the line to animate in from the top, down to about the middle of the canvas, and then back out to the top. After being rotated however, it comes in from the right and goes out right, since the whole context has been rotated (my example code below). I've tried inserting the animate tag just before the ending group element, and have also tried the animateTransform tag. The animate tag just before the ending group tag did nothing, and the animateTransform tag gave me movement, but the line was horizontal again, in the wrong position, and it did not honor my keySplines values (easing). I need some way to keep my element transformed, but be able to animate in/out from the top/right/bottom/left per the user's instructions.

I need an inline, SVG solution (as opposed to CSS). The application is a video slide editor that exports this block of code that is rendered on a player written in HTML/SVG. My slide editor uses Fabric JS to edit and export the SVG elements.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 992 558" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="position:absolute; width:100%; left:0; background-color: null" id="svg">
  <desc>Created with Fabric.js 3.6.3</desc>
  <defs></defs>
  <g transform="matrix(0 0.68 -1 0 455.92 235.39)">
    <line style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 4; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; visibility: hidden;" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" x1="-175" y1="0" x2="175" y2="0" layerId="1">
      <animate attributeName="y1" attributeType="XML" begin="0.7441050156739812s" dur="1.25s" values="-1000; 0" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.14 0.22 0.12 0.99" />
      <set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin="0.7441050156739812s" />
      <animate attributeName="y2" attributeType="XML" begin="0.7441050156739812s" dur="1.25s" values="-1000; 0" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.14 0.22 0.12 0.99" />
      <set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin="0.7441050156739812s" />
      <animate attributeName="y1" attributeType="XML" begin="2.132496081504702s" dur="1.25s" values="0; -1000" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.7 0 0.53 0.99" />
      <set attributeName="visibility" from="visible" to="hidden" begin="4.132496081504701s" />
      <animate attributeName="y2" attributeType="XML" begin="2.132496081504702s" dur="1.25s" values="0; -1000" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.7 0 0.53 0.99" />
      <set attributeName="visibility" from="visible" to="hidden" begin="4.132496081504701s" />
    </line>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is it acceptable for your use case to alter the `x` and `y` attributes to rotate the line that way, or are there more (and different) elements inside that group?

Comment: If you run the code snippet, you can see that the line is vertical. That is the intent. What I want it to do is to stay vertical, but slide in from the top, and back out to the top off the canvas. Right now it slides in/out from/to the right, since the entire group, including the animation tags have been transformed.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure my comment above was misunderstood, so I provide a basic answer using the technique I had in mind.

Instead of rotating the whole group, to make a vertical line, instead get rid of the rotation on the group and instead set the `x1`, `x2` and `y1` and `y2` coordinates in such a way, that you get a vertical line. That way you can then easily apply the animation, without anything beeing rotated. The basic idea is outlined below:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 992 558" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="position:absolute; width:100%; left:0; background-color: null" id="svg">
  <desc>Created with Fabric.js 3.6.3</desc>
  <defs></defs>
  <g>
    <line style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 4; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; visibility: hidden;" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" x1="10" y1="-175" x2="10" y2="175" layerId="1">
      <animate attributeName="y1" attributeType="XML" begin="0.7441050156739812s" dur="1.25s" values="0; 500" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.14 0.22 0.12 0.99" />
      <set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin="0.7441050156739812s" />
      <animate attributeName="y2" attributeType="XML" begin="0.7441050156739812s" dur="1.25s" values="-350; 150" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.14 0.22 0.12 0.99" />
      <set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin="0.7441050156739812s" />
    </line>
  </g>
</svg>
```

However you can also just take the rotation into account when animating the properties (and therefore then animate the `x1` and `x2` properties instead of `y1` and `y2`):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 992 558" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="position:absolute; width:100%; left:0; background-color: null" id="svg">
  <desc>Created with Fabric.js 3.6.3</desc>
  <defs></defs>
  <g transform="matrix(0 0.68 -1 0 455.92 235.39)">
    <line style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 4; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; visibility: hidden;" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" x1="-175" y1="0" x2="175" y2="0" layerId="1">
      <animate attributeName="x1" attributeType="XML" begin="0.7441050156739812s" dur="1.25s" values="-1000; 0" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.14 0.22 0.12 0.99" />
      <set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin="0.7441050156739812s" />
      <animate attributeName="x2" attributeType="XML" begin="0.7441050156739812s" dur="1.25s" values="-650; 350" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.14 0.22 0.12 0.99" />
      <set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin="0.7441050156739812s" />
      <animate attributeName="x1" attributeType="XML" begin="2.132496081504702s" dur="1.25s" values="0; -1000" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.7 0 0.53 0.99" />
      <set attributeName="visibility" from="visible" to="hidden" begin="4.132496081504701s" />
      <animate attributeName="x2" attributeType="XML" begin="2.132496081504702s" dur="1.25s" values="350; -650" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.7 0 0.53 0.99" />
      <set attributeName="visibility" from="visible" to="hidden" begin="4.132496081504701s" />
    </line>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Also bear in mind, that `x1` and `x2` must keep the same distance (which was `350` in the code you posted).